# Unable to loop through the options inside a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this select list, as follow:-

[image]

```
<input type="text" value="Departmental Folder Structure Clean up" maxlength="255" id="Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField" title="Title Required Field" style="ime-mode : " class="ms-long ms-spellcheck-true" disabled="disabled">
<select id="ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_b60c7117-fab9-43ec-8c10-4e714969dd20_SelectCandidate" multiple="multiple" title="Active Dependant Projects possible values" style="width: 300px; height: 125px; overflow: scroll;">
<option value="68" title=" .......Laptop/PC replacement Project"> ... Laptop/PC replacement Project</option>
<option value="83" title="3.....Deployment ">... Deployment </option>
<option value="108" title=".....sion">...g Session</option></select>
```

now i want to remove the option which have a title = to the tile field, so i tried this:-

```
var titlevalue = $('input[id^="Title_"]').val();
var currentprojecttitle = $($("[id^=ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_][id$=_SelectCandidate]")[0]);
for (var i=0; i<currentprojecttitle.length; i++) {
   if (currentprojecttitle.options[i].value == titlevalue)
      currentprojecttitle.remove(i);
}
```

but i got this error:-

> uncaught type error: can not read a property of '0' of undefined

although in my case `$($("[id^=ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_][id$=_SelectCandidate]")[0])` is correctly referencing the select list, because when i run this `$($("[id^=ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_][id$=_SelectCandidate]")[0]).css('width','300px');` it increased the width.

Comment: Could you also add your html using that same id for the select element?

Comment: Any chance you can give us the html, or make a fiddle so we can test it?

Comment: @justDan the picture include the HTML for the select list and its options

Comment: @WesleySmith the picture include the HTML for the select list and its option

Comment: No I meant include the html, not a picture. We can't test a picture.

Comment: We dont want a picture, we want the html, we dont want to re-write it to test solutions for you...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @WesleySmith ok sorry for that , updated

Comment: @Shiny ok sorry for that , i updated the question with the markup

Comment: `i = 0 to currentprojecttitle.length` bears no relevance to `currentprojecttitle.options[i].value` - you probably wanted `for (var i=0; i<currentprojecttitle.options.length`

Comment: Then, if you have two options with the same value, you'll miss one if they're next to each other (so better to go in reverse order) - if you don't (and can't) then just add a `break` after the `.remove()` (inside the if)

Comment: Also, `currentprojecttitle.options` will be null because `currentprojecttitle` is a jquery object - so you want `currentprojecttitle.find("option")[i]`

Comment: Finally, although it has no impact on your question: try to break away from the reliance on `id=` - you don't need it and it's making a mess of your code because you know IDs have to be unique so you (or whomever generated this code, no doubt you have no control over this) went with "ids=unique" and "reference everything via an id" and came up with the horrendous mess you have now with the guids in the ids.  Use classes - they don't need to be only for css.

Comment: @freedomn-m i tried `currentprojecttitle.find("option")[i]` and the error has gone, but the option which match the title did not get removed.. so do i need to modify `currentprojecttitle.remove(i);`.??. second point, regarding the ids, i am working against sharepoint page, so the full id might get changed, which the text i am searching inside the id will remain.

Comment: Ah, sharepoint, explains a lot - microsoft not knowing what they're doing *again*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simpler to set `var currentprojecttitle = $("[id^=ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_][id$=_SelectCandidate]")[0];`. In your code, you wrap that into a jquery variable, but you then use it as a javascript variable. You can see a demo [here](https://codepen.io/mohingudino/pen/MWYZMeo). I added the corresponding class to the `Deployment` option, and it is removed.

Comment: Your original code would not work. You need to change the definition of `currentprojecttitle` as explained in the answer.

Comment: using `var currentprojecttitle = $("[id^=ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_][id$=_SelectCandidate]")[0];` has removed the error, but the option did not get removed from the select list.

Comment: Please, have a look at the demo. I have changed it to suit your original question. Notice that the conditional is now `currentprojecttitle.options[i].title == titlevalue`. Previously, you were checking the value, not the title. Also notice that the second option is `<option value="83" title="Departmental Folder Structure Clean up">... Deployment </option>`, so the that `title` is the same as the test. Also notice that this option is removed from the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are working on the jQuery element of the select. You must do this:

```
var titlevalue = $('input[id^="Title_"]').val();
var currentprojecttitle = $($("[id^=ProjectDependantProjectsLookup_][id$=_SelectCandidate]")[0]);
for (var i=0; i<currentprojecttitle.length; i++) {
   if (currentprojecttitle[0].options[i].value == titlevalue)//Selecting the first element of the jQuery collection
      currentprojecttitle[0].remove(i);
}
```

Comment: your code will raise the same error on `currentprojecttitle.Options.length`